# Displaying a JSON array in PHP (from freebase)

Tags: php, parsing, json, freebase

This is a very basic question, so excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to output a JSON query from Freebase in PHP. I've already been able to parse the JSON into PHP using cURL and json_decode.

Here is a link to the JSON array (for some reason I can't get this to link directly):
http://www.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query={%20%22query%22%3A%20[{%20%22type%22%3A%20%22%2Fpeople%2Fperson%22%2C%20%22ns0%3Atype%22%3A%20%22%2Fbase%2Fbillionaires%2Fbillionaire%22%2C%20%22employment_history%22%3A%20[{%20%22company%22%3A%20null%20}]%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20null%20}]%20}

I'm able to ouput the first level of the array (Bill Gates), but not the 2nd level (Microsoft).

I've figured out how to display and loop through the people's names, just not their associated companies.

So my code, thus far, gets me a list of names.

```
$results = json_decode($response)->result;
foreach ($results as $name) {
echo $name->name . '<br/>';
```

I want the companies associated with each name to be displayed.

The browser-format should be:

Person 1 Name:
Company Name 1
Company Name 2
etc.

Person 2 Name:
Company Name 1
etc.

Thanks for any pointers--I'm sure that I'm just missing the simple way to structure the PHP code to display this easily.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
$results = json_decode($response)->result;
foreach ($results as $person) {
    echo $person->name . '<br/>';
    foreach($person->employment_history as $employer) {
        echo $employer->company . '<br/>';
    }
    echo '<hr />'; // horizontal rule for good measure
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to mark it as the answer to the question. Happy Holidays!

Comment: "Don't forget to mark it as the answer to the question", almost 3 years ago :P